# Question about theorem involving the definition of derivatives of measures

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am working through Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (I have the first edition) and in his chapter on Differentiation, he begins with the following theorem:

[image]

I understand the proof of how (a) implies (b) but I'm a little confused about his proof of how (b) implies (a).  His proof is as follows:
[image]

My question is this: Once we have (3) above, isn't (3) sufficient to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(s,t)$ and therefore that $f$ is continuous at $ x \space \epsilon \space (s,t)$?  Why do we need to show that $ \mu(\{x\})=0$ to establish that $f$ is continuous at $x$?  On a related note, why does the fact that property (b) holds imply that $ \mu(\{x\})=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated to correct my own oversight.]

[Updated once more to account for the fact that $\mu$ is complex.]

First, (3) does not imply uniform continuity on $(s,t)$ because it does not hold for arbitrary $s',t'\in(s,t)$, but only on the restriction that $s'<x<t'$.

Now, if $\mu$ were valued in $[0,\infty)$, then $f$ would be monotone, and so you could still use (3) to establish continuity at the point $x$, via the monotonicity of $f$.  In this case you wouldn't have to directly argue $\mu(\{x\})=0$.

Since $\mu$ is complex, however, we follow Rudin's approach. The reason $\mu(\{x\})=0$ implies continuity at $x$ is that the left hand limit is

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow x^-}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow x^-}\mu((-\infty,z)) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{z<x}(-\infty,z)\right)= \mu((-\infty, x)) =f(x)\text{,} $$

whereas the right hand limit is

\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow x^+}f(z) &=\lim_{z\rightarrow x^+}\mu((-\infty,z)) = \mu\left(\bigcap_{z>x}(-\infty,z)\right)\\
&= \mu((-\infty, x]) =\mu((-\infty,x)\cup \{x\}) = f(x)+\mu(\{x\})\text{.}
\end{align*}

Note that the unions and intersections in the above reasoning can be taken to be countable by the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.

Finally, to answer your question of how (b) implies $\mu(\{x\})=0$, observe that otherwise as the interval $I$ goes to $0$ in length,  $\left|\mu(I)/m(I)\right|\rightarrow \infty$, contradicting (2).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!  That makes sense now.  Can you elaborate on how the fact that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ implies the continuity of f at x?  I'm still a little confused on that part.

Comment: Actually just realized my explanation was flawed, I overlooked the fact that $\mu$ was a complex measure (You'd think the book title should have clued me in;) ).  In any case, I updated the answer to elaborate.